# How to pass a local variable to a promise done function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following script, which runs 5 ajax requests and tells when they are done. All that using jQuery promises and `$.where`.

http://jsfiddle.net/r269j65r/

```
console.info('Creating promises: start');
var p = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    a = $.when( x(i) ).done(function(){
        console.log('Promise ' + i + ': done');
    });
    p.push(a);
}
console.info('Creating promises: done');
console.log('Running promises: start');

$.when.apply($,p).done(function(){
    console.log('Running promises: done');
});

function x(i) {
    console.log('Promise ' + i + ': start');
    return $.ajax({
        'url' : '/'         
    })
    .done( function() {
    });
}
```

The problem is that `console.log('Promise ' + i + ': done');` always returns `Promise 5: done`, because `i`-variable has value `5` when the `done()` function is executed.

My question is what be a good and clean way to give `i` to the context of the `done()`-function in the `for`-loop?

Comment: Just put it in that `x` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use closure to make this work ([Closures on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures))

A working fragment:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    (function(i){
        a = $.when( x(i) ).done(function(){
            console.log('Promise ' + i + ': done');
        });
        p.push(a);
    })(i);
}
```

And the full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r269j65r/1/)...